# Will an application built for Windows Phone 7.0 work with 7.1?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I have built my app for WP7.0 - will it still work on WP7.1?

Do I need to rebuild it using WP7.1 sdk? If yes, how can i rebuild my current app to 7.1 mango?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your 7.0-built application will work as expected in 7.1, but the fast application switching (multitasking) experience may not be optimal.

To rebuild/optimise your application for Mango:

1. Install the [updated tools](http://create.msdn.com/en-us/home/getting_started) (currently RC)
2. In the Properties pane of the application, change "Target Windows Phone OS Version" to "Windows Phone OS 7.1"
3. Update your code in `App_Activated` to only process the state if [`ActivatedEventArgs.IsApplicationInstancePreserved`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.shell.activatedeventargs.isapplicationinstancepreserved%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) is `false`

Keep in mind that, [for the next few weeks](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2011/09/20/submit-windows-phone-7-5-apps-today-update-7-0-apps-in-october.aspx), you cannot release a bug fix for users with 7.0 once you release a 7.1 build.

Comment: Fast application switching (which is NOT multitasking, as it still tombstones your app) requires a re-compilation to 7.1

Comment: @AnthonyWJones - Very broken. Thanks for the heads up.